# What should I annotate when I unit test the GPS function with Robolectric?

Tags: unit-testing, annotations, robolectric

I am referring the following site http://googletesting.blogspot.ca/2010/12/test-sizes.html . There it was mentioned that we should annotate `@LargeTest` if our test method is accessing the network feature. I am using `Roboloectric` for unit testing.
And my method uses the `shadowLocationManager` to simulate the GPS location. I am not sure what should I annotate for my `GPSTest`. Should I go for `@Test` or go for `@LargeTest`. I just started learning the unit testing with `Robolectric`. I been using `@Test` annotation for all my tests so far and I didn't face a problem. Can someone please suggest me the proper annotation to be followed for `Robolectric`.

Edit: The `@SmallTest`,`@MediumTest`,`@LargeTest` annotation failed in my GPS Test and `@Test` passed the test. Are these annotations doesn't work on `Robolectric`? If so,then how can I mark my tests with different annotations?

If you want to have a look at my test method,please look at the following code:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
  mainActivity = new Settings();
  mainActivity=Robolectric.buildActivity(Settings.class).create().get();
}
@Test
public void shouldReturnTheLatestLocation() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
            Robolectric.application.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    ShadowLocationManager shadowLocationManager = Robolectric.shadowOf(locationManager);
    Location expectedLocation = location(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 12.0, 20.0);

    shadowLocationManager.simulateLocation(expectedLocation);

  System.out.print("expected location is "+expectedLocation.getLatitude()+expectedLocation.getLongitude());
    Location actualLocation = mainActivity.latestLocation();
   System.out.print("actual location is "+actualLocation.getLatitude()+actualLocation.getLongitude());
    assertEquals(expectedLocation, actualLocation);
}
```

BottomLine: (I think I can expect an upvote now...Feeling proud :D :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, those annotations are not for Robolectric.

They are useful when using the Android InstrumentationTestRunner which runs tests on device.

Robolectric runs tests on the JVM, different beast altogether.

Comment: So it is just one annotation for all types of tests right?